# Service is accessible even after Eureka is shutdown

Tags: netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I have two Microservices, MS1 and MS2 both registered with Eureka server. MS1 invokes MS2. I found that even after I shutdown the Eureka server, I am able to run MS1 without any error. If the Eureka server is down how is MS1 able to figure out details of MS2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact every eureka client has a cache for all the server info in eureka server, so the ribbon loadbalancer in eureka client don't have to query eureka server in every request, and the cache refreshes every 30 seconds by default.

That's why your MS1 server can still work even after you shutting down the eureka server.